# AWA Apache Airflow (MWAA) - unable to SSH instance in private subnet

Tags: amazon-web-services, mwaa

we are running MWAA and we are trying to make a SSH connection from MWAA in EC2 instance, which is running in a private subnet. Connection fails on [Errno None] Unable to connect to port 22 on .

it looks like a network issue, but I done see what should be configured

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

If the MWAA environment and EC2 instance are in same VPC, your EC2 instance's security group should allow SSH (TCP 22) from MWAA env's security group or subnet CIDR range. If they are in different VPCs, you need to have proper network path/routing in between the two VPCs, such as VPC Peering or Transit Gateway.

Comment: they are in the same. After a couple of hours with AWS support, we were told that this is not possible. That EC2 instance should have an elastic IP attached, so should have a public IP address